# Implement modal before saving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I am working on an app where Admin can publish a welcome message to the public.
I need to implement a modal before Publishing the message, basically, after they click ‘Publish to Public page’ show a warning which says “You are about to publish this content to the world, on your public status page. It will be visible to all internet users, not just your colleagues. Click ‘OK’ to publish or ‘Cancel’ to go back.

At the stage when I click on publish this directly saves the welcome message, I am having trouble displaying the modal.

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="row" id="notice-edit-container" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <i><%= t('statusx.guide_text')%></i><br />
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="message-form" action="<%= public_page_path %>" method="post" data-image-path="<%= upload_image_noticeboards_path %>">
            <textarea class="noticeEditor" name="content" style="width: 100%; height:340px;">
              <%= @welcome_message %>
            </textarea>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :_method, "put" %>
            <%= t('statusx.public_page_link')%>
            <%= link_to "https://demo.getvetter.com/public", target: :_blank %>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary tn-w-m"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#approvalMessageModal">
            <%= t('statusx.save') %></button>
            <button id="cancel_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-w-m"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
          </form>
        </div> <!-- end ibox-content -->
      </div> <!-- end ibox -->
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="approvalMessageModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="approvalMessageModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><%= t('statusx.popup.warning') %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="notice-read-ok btn btn-primary btn-block"  data-dismiss="modal"><%= t('ok') %></button>
      <button id="cancel_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-w-m"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    // Warning modal before publish welcome message

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#approvalMessageModal').modal('show');
});
```

I would appreciate help to display the modal and save data.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Remove the submit type from the button inside the form and on the click of the button popup the modal box.
And on the action of ok button inside modal box submit the form.

```html
<div class="row" id="notice-edit-container" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <i><%= t('statusx.guide_text')%></i><br />
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id='myForm' class="message-form" action="<%= public_page_path %>" method="post" data-image-path="<%= upload_image_noticeboards_path %>">
            <textarea class="noticeEditor" name="content" style="width: 100%; height:340px;">
              <%= @welcome_message %>
            </textarea>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :_method, "put" %>
            <%= t('statusx.public_page_link')%>
            <%= link_to "https://demo.getvetter.com/public", target: :_blank %>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button
            class="btn btn-primary tn-w-m"
            id='saveButton'
            >
            <%= t('statusx.save') %></button>
            <button id="cancel_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-w-m"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
          </form>
        </div> <!-- end ibox-content -->
      </div> <!-- end ibox -->
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="approvalMessageModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="approvalMessageModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p><%= t('statusx.popup.warning') %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="notice-read-ok btn btn-primary btn-block"  data-dismiss="modal" id='submitForm'><%= t('ok') %></button>
      <button id="cancel_submit" class="btn btn-default btn-w-m"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#saveButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#approvalMessageModal').modal('show');
    return false;
  });
  $('#submitForm').on('click', function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
  });
});
```

I have not tested the code. Hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks @rzkmr
I have tried removing <button> type Attribute, adding ids as above but it does not work and used javascript function but when i click on my button to save nothing is happening.